# Regex match from digit to digit?

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to regex from digit to digit?

I have this tracklist:

```
01. Intro 02. Waage 03. Hyänen (feat. Samra) 04. Ich will es bar (feat. Haftbefehl) 05. Am Boden bleiben (feat. Casper & Montez) 06. Panzerglas (feat. Face) 07. Sobald Du gehst 08. 90’s (feat. Olson) 09. Erzähl‘ mir nix (feat. Nio) 10. Dope & 40s 11. Lila (feat. Bosca) 12. Wo ich wohn‘ 13. Bahnen 14. 200K
```

which I tried to split with `/\d\d([^\d]*)/g` into objects. But I got as a result:

```
0: ""
1: ". Intro "
2: ""
3: ". Waage "
4: ""
5: ". Hyänen (feat. Samra) "
6: ""
7: ". Ich will es bar (feat. Haftbefehl) "
8: ""
9: ". Am Boden bleiben (feat. Casper & Montez) "
10: ""
11: ". Panzerglas (feat. Face) "
12: ""
13: ". Sobald Du gehst "
14: ""
15: ". "
16: ""
17: "’s (feat. Olson) "
18: ""
19: ". Erzähl‘ mir nix (feat. Nio) "
20: ""
21: ". Dope & "
22: ""
23: "s "
24: ""
25: ". Lila (feat. Bosca) "
26: ""
27: ". Wo ich wohn‘ "
28: ""
29: ". Bahnen "
30: ""
31: ". "
32: ""
33: ""
34: "0K"
```

How do I include the numbers `01`, `02`, `03`... and what are the possibilites for cases like track 14 where the title track is `200k`?

Comment: have a try with this one `/\D(?=\d+\.\s)/g`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```js
text.split(/\s+(?=\d+\.\s)/)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/OCeGBD/1). *Details*:

- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(?=\d+\.\s)` - a positive lookahead that requires one or more digits, `.` and a whitespace to occur immediately to the right of the current location.

See the JavaScript demo:

```js
const text = "01. Intro 02. Waage 03. Hyänen (feat. Samra) 04. Ich will es bar (feat. Haftbefehl) 05. Am Boden bleiben (feat. Casper & Montez) 06. Panzerglas (feat. Face) 07. Sobald Du gehst 08. 90’s (feat. Olson) 09. Erzähl‘ mir nix (feat. Nio) 10. Dope & 40s 11. Lila (feat. Bosca) 12. Wo ich wohn‘ 13. Bahnen 14. 200K";
text.split(/\s+(?=\d+\.\s)/).forEach( x =>
  console.log(x))
```

If you need to make sure the bullet numbers come in incrementally, you need to adjust the code to

```js
const text = "01. Intro containing 26. chars 02. Waage 03. Hyänen (feat. Samra) 04. Ich will es bar (feat. Haftbefehl) 05. Am Boden bleiben (feat. Casper & Montez) 06. Panzerglas (feat. Face) 07. Sobald Du gehst 08. 90’s (feat. Olson) 09. Erzähl‘ mir nix (feat. Nio) 10. Dope & 40s 11. Lila (feat. Bosca) 12. Wo ich wohn‘ 13. Bahnen 14. 200K";
var chunks = text.split(/\s+(?=\d+\.\s)/)
chunks = chunks.reduce(
    function(acc, currentValue, index) {
      if (index>0) {
        const num = Number(currentValue.match(/^\d+/)[0])
        if (num - num_prev === 1) {
            acc.push(currentValue); num_prev = num;
        } else {
            acc[acc.length-1] += ` ${currentValue}`;
        }
        return acc;
      } else {
          acc = [currentValue]; num_prev = 1;
          return acc;
      }
    }, [])
chunks.forEach( x =>
  console.log(x))
```